# Can't write dictionary to plist objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

Through searching the internet I have come up with some code that should retrieve data from a plist and write data to a plist. I can retrieve data just fine but storing data isn't working.
Here is my store Data method:

```
- (void)saveData {
[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.todayHours] forKey:@"TimeOutOfBraceHours"];
[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.todayMinutes] forKey:@"TimeOutOfBraceMinutes"];
[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.overallHours] forKey:@"OverallHours"];
[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.overallMinutes] forKey:@"OverallMinutes"];
[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.goalForWeek] forKey:@"WeeklyGoal"];
NSString *plistCatPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *rootDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistCatPath];
[rootDictionary setObject:self.time forKey:@"Time"];
[rootDictionary writeToFile:plistCatPath atomically:YES];
}
```

The NSMutableDictionary

```
self.time
```

is declared in the implementation.

Here is the read data method:

```
- (void)retreiveData {
NSString *plistCatPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *rootDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistCatPath];
self.time = rootDictionary[@"Time"];
NSLog(@"%@", self.time[@"TimeOutOfBraceHours"]);
self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.todayHours = [[self.time objectForKey:@"TimeOutOfBraceHours"] intValue];
self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.todayMinutes = [[self.time objectForKey:@"TimeOutOfBraceMinutes"] intValue];
self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.overallHours = [[self.time objectForKey:@"OverallHours"] intValue];
self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.overallMinutes = [[self.time objectForKey:@"OverallMinutes"] intValue];
self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.goalForWeek = [[self.time objectForKey:@"WeeklyGoal"] intValue];
}
```

When I run the program it just retrieves the data that I manually put into the plist instead of the data that was supposedly stored in it on the last run.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You people just **can't be bothered to use Google...**

Comment: I did use google maybe i didnt search the write thing cuz im sorta just learning objective c write now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to write to a file in the bundle. The only places you are allowed to write to are the caches directory (not what you want) and the documents directory.

```
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFile"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];

[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.todayHours] forKey:@"TimeOutOfBraceHours"];
[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.todayMinutes]  forKey:@"TimeOutOfBraceMinutes"];
[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.overallHours] forKey:@"OverallHours"];
[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.overallMinutes] forKey:@"OverallMinutes"];
[self.time setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.brace.timeOutOfBrace.goalForWeek] forKey:@"WeeklyGoal"];
NSString *plistCatPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *rootDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistCatPath];
[rootDictionary setObject:self.time forKey:@"Time"];

[rootDictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: How should I go about doing this?

Comment: How should I change my code to save to the document directory?

Comment: Okay that seemed to work but how would I go about retrieving this data?

Comment: Just have something like `NSDictionary *foo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];`